# jquery countdown get minutes and seconds

Tags: jquery, countdown

Hi
I am able to embed countdown timer from [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

but as here in "Miscellaneous" tab there is GetTime section. where as said "Periods" is an array and we able to pick minutes and seconds by "Periods[5]" for minutes and "Periods[6]" form seconds (Please see its documentation [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#getTimes)). I used same code . i am able to fetch the data but it is not behaving like array. this is my code:

```
var min=10;
var sec=30;

  $('#eachQTimer').countdown({ until: '+' + min + 'm +' + sec + 's', format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2 });

 var periods = $('#eachQTimer').countdown('getTimes');
alert(periods); // I tried :alert(periods[5]); / alert(periods[5].val());
```

it is showing me out put as : 0,0,0,0,0,10,30. on alert box. which is fine. but why am unable to get 5 indexed value then ? not executing latter single line of code after this line 
and if i use :  `alert(periods[5].value); then getting undefined .`

Comment: According to the documentation you link to (and to the plugin source code), `getTimes` indeed returns an array, so `periods[5]` and `periods[6]` should work. Can you elaborate what happens when you do that?

Comment: `alert(periods[5])` works for me, See: http://jsfiddle.net/WDA8g/

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi , nothing happening there. means that line and after that line is not executing. I checked it by adding alert before and after of line . later alert not executed

Comment: looks like an exception is raised, can you look for it in the error console?

Answer (score 0):

Add a click function.

```
var min = 10;
var sec = 30;

$('#eachQTimer').countdown({ 
  until: '+' + min + 'm +' + sec + 's', 
  format: 'YOWDHMS', 
  significant: 2
});

$('#getTime').click(function() {
  var periods = $('#eachQTimer').countdown('getTimes');
  alert(periods[6]);
});
```